# Extract image url from bb code with attribute

Tags: php

I have some image BB Codes like this

```
[IMG]imageurlhere[/IMG]

[IMG alt="image alt here"]imageurl[/IMG]

[IMG alt="image alt here" title="image title"]imageurl[/IMG]
```

I used this to get image url

```
preg_match_all('/\[(img|IMG)\]\s*(https?:\/\/([^*\r\n]+|[a-z0-9\/\\\._\- !]+))\[\/(img|IMG)\]/Ui', $stringContainBbCode, $matches);
$urls = $matches[0];
```

But i can only get image url in the first case. How can I do with two remaining cases ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `()?` block to check for optional content like the "s" in "https" you are checking with `s?`. Use it to check if the `alt` attribute is present or not. The regex would be something like this:

```
/\[(img|IMG)(\s+alt="(?P<alt>[^"]+)")?(\s+title="(?P<title>[^"]+)")?\]\s*(https?:\/\/([^*\r\n]+|[a-z0-9\/\\\._\- !]+))\[\/(img|IMG)\]/Ui
```

Note that in this regex the "alt" attribute must be before the "title" attribute, if both are present.